# Datatables - Responsive not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am trying to understand why Datatables (https://datatables.net/) Responsive wouldn't be working. Everything else is working great, paging, searching, ordering, etc.. but not responsive?

Below is what I have.

Bootstrap v3.3.6

```js
$(function () {
    $('#ManageUsers').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        lengthChange: true,
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        info: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        responsive: true
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>


<!-- CODE -->

<table id="ManageUsers" class="table table-bordered table-striped display responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if you have missed any required file or any file that conflicts. Check one by one. That may lead to help.

Comment: ? Not sure I follow? @AT-2016

Comment: Pls create and show your fiddle

Comment: A codepen or jsfiddle might help us understand what exactly went wrong

Comment: Any progress with that?@Kray

Comment: I was able to get it fixed with a conjunction of both of the answers provided. Thank you. @OffirPe'er

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try loading the libraries in this order like in the **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ej9ChauL90wTBnh741yz?p=preview)**.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script data-require="datatables@*" data-semver="1.10.12" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/dataTables.responsive.css"/>
<link data-require="datatables@*" data-semver="1.10.12" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are missing
  https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css in
  your header and missed nowrap in class according to their examples.
- I personally would suggest to initiate responsive dataTable via javascript as
  it will provide more options to customise your UI.

Please refer to these links for reference
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/default.html
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/className.html
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/option.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using width=100% in table. Not pretty, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this script at the bottom of your file

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#manageUsers").DataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "autoWidth": false, 
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            responsive: true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": "data.js",
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name[, ]" },
            { "data": "hr.0" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "hr.2" },
            { "data": "hr.1" }
    });
  </script>
```

It worked for me.